# ESC/POS commands, Ionic application

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, bluetooth, escpos

Im developing an android app and im trying to make a print on a thermal printer.
The printer model is: http://www.rongtatech.com/products-look-89.html

I have searched a lot of guides , questions/answers etc but im not able to make a single print or even to do something with the printer.

I'm making a connection with ionic bluetooth serial native: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/

So im using the `bluetoothSerial.write` method to send data.
I can find the printer via bluetooth and make a succefull connection.

One example of what im doing after i have a connection with the bluetooth is this.

```
print(){
    let data = new Uint8Array(2);
    data[0] = 0x1B;//Esc
    data[1] = 0x0a;// nl - new line
    data[2] = 0x00A;//LF - linefeed
    this.bluetoothSerial.write(data)
        .then(res=>{
        alert('print sucess');
    })
        .catch(error=>{
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

I also have tried data as a string. Didnt work ofcourse.

```
let data = 'hello\n\n';
```

The printer seems to get the signal when i send the data, becouse it open from sleep mode. But do nothing with them.

So its obvius something is not correct on how i sending the data. 
I dont know if the problem is the hexcodes order, the type im sending the data or both of them.

Thnx for any help.